# How can I remove existing fields in the default User DB in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I have created and AbstractUser with some fields that I want the User Class to have. But after successfully creating a new User Model, the user table now has the previous columns (the ones which would have been added on migration of the default User Model) and also has the columns which I have added in the Custom User Model.

Is there a way to remove the columns which are added by default?

Here's my models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ''' SOME UNIQUE FIELDS '''
    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
        db_table = 'users'
```

These are the fields that appear even without specifying in the model. How can I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you are *extending* the model `AbstractUser`, it has all the fields of that class, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user.

If you want a complete custom user, you should extend `AbstractBaseUser.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So now, most of the extra columns have gone except for 2 columns (password, last_login). I don't require password as I'm only using social login. 

Any way to get rid of these two columns?